# Mocking with domain values

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am wondering how can i set domain values or range of values on mocking.

```
trait MyInt{
     def getInt():Int
}


trait MyString{
     def getName():String
}
```

I have tried some but nothing works.
I like to define a mock of `MyInt` to return values from `(0,100)`
and `MyString` trait to return values from this domain: `{"Dani",Jonny",Jessica",....}`.

How can i write that using scalatest?

Answer (score 3):

Using mockito plus scalatest

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import scala.util.Random

class FirstSpec extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

    "The mock" should "pick a value from the interval" in {
        val mockInt = mock[MyInt]
        val mockStr = mock[MyString]

        when(mockInt.getInt()).thenReturn(pickOneFrom(1 to 100 toList))
        when(mockStr.getName()).thenReturn(pickOneFrom(List("Dani", "Jonny", "Jessica")))

        println(mockInt.getInt())
        println(mockStr.getName())

    }
```

}

where pickOne would be defined as

```
def pickOneFrom[T](domain: List[T]) = domain(Random.nextInt(domain.length))
```

Comment: It's all fine, but I bet that `Random` should be only instantiated once, not on every method call due to how pseudo-random number generators work. :)